# How does this wheel menu get the name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Guys please see this site '...', I like to have a wheel menu like that. So can you tell me in this [website](http://www.eidparry.com/),
how this menu tabs get the names from '...' I'm searching for the **ul li tags** but there is just this

```
<div class="menu" id="holder"></div>
```

In CSS,

```
.menu { 
    position:absolute;
    /*bottom:0;*/
    top:40px;
    left:0px;
    z-index:201; /*new */
    width:auto;
    }
```

The JavaScript,

- [javascript](http://jsfiddle.net/zain0788/8xza5/)

Comment: Your question is unclear. "How this menu gets nav names from"??

Comment: @Tilwin: I mean the menu tabs. . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site you mentioned is using SVG(Scalable Vector Graphics for displaying its menu. You will not find any ul tags or something, they are SVG's path tags. For more information you can try w3c resources on SVG on how to work with it:[w3c SVG page](http://www.w3schools.com/SVG/default.asp).